# Export function lists (with parameters) from lots of C files

Tags: visual-studio, function

I have an old VC 6.0 project with lots of C files. I need to document all the methods with their signatures, for example, listed them in a txt file like:

```
LoadTranCde(LKFD lkfd, char * msg, char * code)

MoveBack(LPT lStm, int numRows)

RTrim(Char * paraString)
....
```

The function list can be easily viewed in Visual Studio class view like:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/9ed31de51c.jpg

But I need to find a way to export this list, anybody has good solution?

Thank you guys very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) yet? It may be overkill for what you're doing, but it's a great, automated way of parsing out function signatures, comments, type definitions, etc. from source code. It can do *much* more if you put in the time to structure code comments in a particular way, but right out of the box it should be able to give you the output you're looking for. You may need to do some post-processing of the text in order to strip away anything unnecessary that doxygen produces.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to generate all the static functions and global functions into a rtf file, and it works.